# Building an SDK

Tags: android, sdk, permissions, broadcastreceiver, server

I have a really simple app that uploads files to a remote server.

I would like to build a SDK, so that external apps can also use the app to upload files. I'm wondering what's the best thing to do for this SDK.

For now, the only thing I've found is to expose a Receiver with a "dangerous" permission in the main app (signature is not conceivable, because "client" apps does not have the same signature).

But I don't really like this solution, because apps without the sdk can also send Intent to the main app.

Do you have another solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It can look a bit complicated, but it sounds like you want to create a Service that other applications can bind to and use via an AIDL.
See the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) for a full explanation/example.